Review issue: post looked disabled
While working on some review queues, I fell upon this one.
I could almost not see the post, as it seemed disabled (the letters were that fainted that I could almost not read them).
As a result, I figured out the post was already deleted, so I decided to confirm that deletion.
Then I got the message that I failed an audit test.
This should not happen: audit tests should look like normal posts, not like deleted (disabled) ones.

FYI, this is likely the same, or at least closely related, issue that was reported $5$ days ago on the network Meta in Some audits became very easy to spot.

@JohnOmielan This has also been reported on other sites, such as having been reported twice already on MSO.

@JohnOmielan: I confirm my issue is indeed the same.

Same thing happening to me… https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/2104385

Hm. This hasn't happened so far in CV. But I have also faced one (and passed) in first post queue here. Perhaps this was due to the fact that it was one of my first reviews here.
